# Nodejs: Detect file type without extension

Tags: node.js

I'm looking to remotely download and detect a file from a website, like this
http://examplewebsite.com/100/download

When viewing in my browser, this automatically downloads as the appropriate file type, `100.pdf`, but sometimes it can be a `.xls` or `.doc` file. etc.

Looking at libraries available, like [file-type](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-type), it only works if you already have the extension

Is this possible?

Comment: You are looking for [mime-types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mime-types)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the url, you can split by '.' and select the last element of your list.

Answer (score 0):

The file-type library you linked in your question actually checks the source of the file to guess. It doesn't use the file extension at all.